# generate an image using og:image dynamically

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla2.5, facebook-opengraph

I need to connect the following to generate an image from the folder dynamically using og:image tag. I've tried so many ways but I've failed all the time. The following is the link:

```
components/com_rdautos/images/lb<?php echo $image[$i];?>
```

Comment: And the code you're using to access it? What does a print_r or var_dump of $image reveal?

Comment: It reveals a series of images in a lightbox<div>  <a href="components/com_rdautos/images/lb<?php echo $image[$i];?> " rel="lightbox[imageset]" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> 
         <img src="components/com_rdautos/assets/images/image.png" border="0" width="<?php echo $width; ?>px" border="0"/></a></div>

Comment: The following is the page of the website: [link](http://www.gauciautomobiles.com/index.php/cars-in-stock/detail/1-alfa-romeo-156#.U0E9D_mSy9T)

Comment: Edit your answer with the contents of print_r

Comment: Thanks for your comments... Tried using the print_r but I think I'm doing something wrong as it is not working for me:    <meta property="og:image" content="components/com_rdautos/images/lb<?php print_r($image[$i]);?>"/>